# Implicit Differentiation- Related Rates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

Suppose that price, $p$ in dollars, and the number of items sold, $x,$ are related by: $p^2 - xp + x^2 = 175.$

If $p$ and $x$ are functions of time, how fast is $p$ changing with respect to time when $p=\$ 10$ and $x$ is increasing by $5$ units per day?

So far I’ve got: $$\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{-2x+p}{2p-x}.$$

Not sure what to do after this? Help would be extremely appreciated :(

Comment: NotAMathWizard, your solution for $dp \over dt$ is not quite correct.  It should be $ \frac {dp}{dt} = \frac {dx}{dt} \frac {-2x+p}{2p-x}$.  (See Adrian Keister's answer below.)  Also, in case the notation is unfamiliar to you, Adrian Keister used a "dot notation" to indicate the derivatives of $x$ and $p$.  My understanding is that is popular with physicists to indicate a derivative with respect to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}[\,p^2-xp+x^2&=175\,] \\
\underbrace{2p\dot{p}}_{\text{Chain}}-\underbrace{(x\dot{p}+\dot{x}p)}_{\text{Product}}+\underbrace{2x\dot{x}}_{\text{Chain}}&=0 \\
\dot{p}(2p-x)&=\dot{x}(p-2x) \\
\dot{p}&=\frac{\dot{x}(p-2x)}{2p-x}.
\end{align*}
The issue is that the problem statement doesn't give you the value of $x$, but of $\dot{x}.$ You can find $x$ by solving the original equation for it when you've plugged in $p=10.$ That is, you are solving
$$100-10x+x^2=175,\qquad\text{or}\qquad x^2-10x-75=0.$$
The solutions are $x=-5, 15.$ Can you rule out one of these? Why?

Comment: The question doesn’t give more detail other then the fact it’s a implicit differentiation question... I’m just stuck where to go.

Comment: Ok, see the edit. Can you continue?